# On Raspbian run multiple python Versions simultaniously

Tags: python, python-3.1, callable-object

I have some old programs from back in the times when python 3.1 came out. 
In the program I often used the `Callable()` to pass a function and it's parameters like this to my TKinter application:

```
tvf.mi(datei_bu, text=datei_opt, command=Callable(exec_datei_opts, datei_opt))
```

Now I wanted to use my programs again but the `callable`- Object was gone. In the web I found that this functionality was removed in python 3.2, and none of the alternatives worked for me.

Finally I decided to reinstall python 3.1. However, I have no idea if it is possible to have multiple python 3 versions installed at the same time or how to 'create' a shell command for this version when I want to use this special version.

My questions are:

- Is there a replacement for the `Callable`- Object that was removed?
- How can I use multiple python versions at the same time?
- How can I create a matching shell command?

Comment: Btw: I'm on Raspbian with a RPi 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem that Python ever had `Callable` built in. You may have confused it with [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) *predicate* which indeed was removed and then brought back:

> New in version 3.2: This function was first removed in Python 3.0 and then brought back in Python 3.2.

All references of `Callable` on the web that I could find point to [swampy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/swampy) package (a by-product of [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python/) book), which has [`swampy.Gui.Callable`](https://github.com/AllenDowney/Swampy/blob/master/python3/Gui.py#L1075):

```
class Callable(object):
    """Wrap a function and its arguments in a callable object.
    Callables can can be passed as a callback parameter and invoked later.
    This code is adapted from the Python Cookbook 9.1, page 302,
    with one change: if call is invoked with args and kwds, they
    are added to the args and kwds stored in the Callable.
    """
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwds):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwds = kwds

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        d = dict(self.kwds)
        d.update(kwds)
        return self.func(*self.args+args, **d)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.func.__name__
```

You can also look at answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36205912/2072035), where OP wanted to reimplement `Callable` for the same purpose.

## Installing Python 3.1

If you still want to try to install the old version of Python 3, you can give the following a try. I assume that Raspbian is Debian-based distro and the same commands apply. Here's the `Dockerfile` that verifies that you can do it on Debian Jessie-compatibe system. You can try the `RUN` commands from it in your shell:

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    # The PPA is designed for Ubuntu, but the trick makes it work
    # because Debian Jessie is compatible with Ubuntu Trusty #
    # on package-level
    sed -i 's/jessie/trusty/g' \
        /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ppa-jessie.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes python3.1

CMD python3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Callable looks suspiciously like `functools.partial`.

Here's partial at work. when i run:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import mul

def do_stuff(num, command):
    return num + command()

for y in range(5):
    print(do_stuff(5, partial(mul, y, 2)))
```

I get:

```
5
7
9
11
13
```

You should be able to do:

```
from functools import partial
tvf.mi(datei_bu, text=datei_opt, command=partial(exec_datei_opts, datei_opt))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `terminal`, run with:

```
python3.1 your_program.py
```

Comment: /usr/bin/python     /usr/bin/python3.4          /usr/bin/python3-config
/usr/bin/python2    /usr/bin/python3.4-config   /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3.4m         /usr/bin/python3m-config
/usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3.4m-config

Comment: WOW! I was told that the package python3.1 is retarded and no longer available, I should use python 3.5 X(

Answer (score 1):

If python 3.1 is unavailable, as seems to be the case from the comments on @JoeIddon answer, you may have to alter your code base. In this case, you can:

#### Monkey patching Callable with functools.partial

has the advantage of avoiding multiple code modifications.

```
from functools import partial
Command = partial
tvf.mi(datei_bu, text=datei_opt, command=Command(exec_datei_opts, datei_opt))
```

#### Alternatively:

**replacing Callable() with lambda** works, but carries the burden of multiple code alterations.

```
tvf.mi(datei_bu, text=datei_opt, command=Callable(exec_datei_opts, datei_opt))
```

replace with:

```
tvf.mi(datei_bu, text=datei_opt, command=lambda x=datei_opt: exec_datei_opts(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

In terminal , give the path where python 3.1 is installed like this:

```
/<python3.1 folder>/bin/python  filename.py
```

Alternatively you can try to create virtual environment and activate it
then you can run the given script
here is the helper link: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 1):

Using `update-alternatives` command. It can help you use python flexibly.

Here's the sample code.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --list python3
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python

$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.4 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.4 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in auto mode
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.5 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in auto mode

$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.4   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a answer to all of my questions. I used a lot of stuff from the answers here in order to solve all my problems. Here they come:

**1) Is there a replacement for the callable object that is gone?**

Basically no. At least none that is working in this context. I will explain why this does not affect my solution.

I made the mistake to just rip out the code out of my TKinter-application without watching my `include`-dependencies. The anwer of saaj made me rethink if had ever used swampy, and indeed I did. I even found the german equivalent ("Programmieren lernen mit python") in my bookshelf. Silly me! X}

I had my GUI components defined in different files, and I just imported them in the `main.py`, my main application.

I was not very advanced in programming so I didn't know that e.g.:

sub.py: (was written long before main.py)

```
import THISISTHEFORGOTTENMODULE

def subfoo(temp=0):
    ... #some Code in which Functions from THISISTHEFORGOTTENMODULE were used
```

main.py:

```
import sub

subfoo()
temp = SuperSpecialFunctionFromForgottenModule()
subfoo(temp)
```

This constellation lead to the behaviour that when I wrote main.py, I didn't have to say `THISISTHEFORGOTTENMODULE.SomeSpeci...`. If I would have written this, I would have known instantly what I would have to import in my new program. When I recently saw this code I thought `Callable` was from the standard library. Unfortunately, there existed a function only different in one character (major C instead of minor c) in python before and was removed. This mislead me to seach for alternatives. Stuff like `functools.partial` (credits to e.s.), would have worked in some situations, thanks for the knowledge, but it didn't work quite a few times.

When I finally found a `from swampy import *` in one of the submodules, I was angry at myself for stepping into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479965/is-there-a-point-to-import-two-different-ways-in-a-program/47480030#47480030) tripwire.(Ironically I was the one that resolved exactly that issue).

Credits in this part to: saaj, e.s., and myself(for the research stuff)

**2)+3) How to install multiple python versions at the same time?**

Well, I had a look at all suggestions and for me, the `update-alternatives` worked out best. I managed to install python3.1 with the suggestions of:

- sanket mokashi (The virtual environement suggestion)
- saaj (The dockerfile stuff worked out as it should)
- Byeongguk Gong (That was the most comfortable way of doing this!)

I just mention this here because it is part of the question, but I didn't need this anymore, I'll just leave the answer here for anyone that passed by and needs it.

---

At the end of writing all this down in a summary of my results, I want to thank all guys who helped me out with this issue.