# Is there a point to import the same module in two different ways in a program?

Tags: python, import, module, package, python-import

Is there a point to import as both wildcard and non-wildcard manner like:

```
import spam as sp
from spam import *
```

in the *very same* file?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. In your second import you can't use it as `sp.` Not that `import *` is sometimes dicouraged. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import).

Comment: It lets more experienced coders who read the program know that the author constructed the script by pasting stuff together from random places and doesn't really know what they're doing. :)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you import spam as sp, you make sure that there are no conflicts with other import commands:

```
import spam as sp
import myfunctions as my

sp.foo()
my.foo()
```

This is working as expected, but this isn't:

```
from spam import *
from myfunctions import *


foo()
foo() #Which foo() is meant? UNCLEAR!!!
```

When you avoid this problem by using `import spam as sp`, why would you want to use `from spam import *` anyways? I don't think there is any point in this.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason that I could think is that you want to *change* from `from spam import *` to `import spam as sp`. If you would just replace those lines, it would instantly break the code, you would have to prefix everything with `sp.`. If you want to do this change at a slower pace, you can do this. Then you can slowely add the `sp.` where needed and eventually remove the `from spam import *`.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Since you have imported `spam` with name `sp` and then imported everything using `from spam import *` `sp` will never be used and is therefore unnecessary.

For example if we have a function called `somefunction()`. `import spam as sp` would mean we could call `somefunction()` with `sp.somefunction()`

Since `from spam import *` it can be called directly `somefunction()` so why use `sp.somefunction()` instead.

`from spam import *` is considered extremely bad practice.  You should import each function individually rather than do that.  (`from spam import somefunction`, `from spam import someotherfunction` and so on).  Or you could just use `sp.somefunction()`, `sp.someotherfunction()`.

Answer (score 2):

`import spam as sp` will load the module and put it into the variable `sp`.
`from spam import *` will load the module and all its attributes (classes, functions, etc...) and also the ones that are imported with a wildcard into `spam` will be accessible.

`import *` is a shortcut when you have a lot of classes, functions you need to access. But it is a bad practice (cf PEP) since you do not encapsulate imported attributes into a namespace (and it's what you do with `import spam as sp`) and can lead to unwanted behavior (if 2 functions have the same name in your main program and into spam)

The best practice, and what states clearly what you'll use is `from spam import func1, func2` or if you will use it a lot `import spam as sp` and use `sp.func1()`